# Stop google chrome from autotranslating, but use the websites multilingual support instead

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internationalization, multilingual

My website has full language support using a dropdown at the top of the page. When the "wrong language" is selected the google chrome translator pop up is show, like in the picture below.

[image]

Instead the pop up showing I would like the website to be translated using my own technology. Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following `meta` tag in the `head` section of your HTML code.

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate" />
```

Beware that if users refreshes the page the translation bar may reappear.